# Best way to save 2D array to MongoDb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

What is the best way to save 2D array, that I have generated,problem is because it won't be small array. So is there a way to convert this 2D array to some JSON format or something and then save that with mongoose, and then to quickly convert it back, the values in are strings, all ideas all appreciated.

This is my schema:

```
var UserRatingSchema = new Schema({
  user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  movie: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie'},
  rating: String, 
});
```

And example of array:
[nothing] Movie1    Movie2 
User1     10      No rating
User2     6         5
...
Is it efficient if I save every instance to database?

Comment: What does your array contain?

Comment: N-d array can be easily converted to JSON; and for MongoDb it doesn't matter what the size is.

Comment: Did you create a schema for your collection that contains 2D arrays?

Comment: You could use embedded document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define model like this,

```
location: {type: [Number]}
```

and define this in schema index like

```
UserSchema.index({location : '2d'});
```

now you structure will be like this

```
 "location": [
        67.0783412,
        24.9044033
    ]
```

you can also modify by adding keys to the values!

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: happy coding :)